# Squid reverse proxy, DMZ, how to forward any non-http request

Tags: proxy, postgresql, squid, ms-sql, dmz

I'm actually facing an issue with some network-protocol related problem.

I have my own domain, a owned DMZ, and externals users. In my DMZ, I have a reverse proxy who handle HTTP connection very well. My external user can hit my inside webserver perfectly.

However, I'd like to know if it's possible for my Squid to do the same with a MSSQL/PGSQL request (or, moreover, any kind of connection).

Like my outside client, hitting my reverse proxy, which will just cache_peer to my real server ?

Regards.

Comment: I can't imagine a web proxy handling a request to an sql server. If e.g. you have sql requests on port 80 (which is weird), then maybe you need some kind of server that checks the type of request and forward to the correct server.

Comment: Yes, it was a very weird solution, but I had poor choice ... then netfilter was my only solution at this moment. :)

Comment: did you use iptables then? you can answer your own question stating what iptables rules you used, it'd be useful to people, and you can accept your own answer. Did you do deep packet inspection?  sounds interesting

Comment: Unfortunately, it was only a raw forwarding to the right server. The only security I had was the source / destination. In term of applicative, only the server receiving packets could verify the integrity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the environment, my only choice was to do a raw forwarding using iptables.

As we had no DPI, everything was forward depending of 3 filters :

- Source
- Destination
- Port

Also, as it had to be transparent, we had to use the host file to set the destination domain as our proxy server. For the destination, no change are needed.

---

```
# My SQL try to contact the dest. SQL (who is in fact, my proxy) so I changed the destination to the real one
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -s [YOUR_INTERNAL_SERVER] -p tcp --dport 15432 -j DNAT --to-destination [YOUR_DESTINATION_SERVER]

# Little restriction
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 15432 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 15432 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p tcp --sport 15432 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# If they contact my SQL, I set the source as my relay so my server could reply back.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -d [YOUR_INTERNAL_SERVER] -p tcp --dport 15432 -j SNAT --to-source [YOUR_PROXY]
```